# React: How to clear form only after SUCCESSFUL submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created a form in React that is cleared after each submission. However, the form is also cleared if the submission is not successful, for example, if a field is filled in incorrectly by the user. This is of course quite annoying, as the user has to repeat the whole process of data entry. So what I'm trying to implement is a clearing that is only activated after a successful submission. If a submission is not successful, the data remains in the form so that the user can rework the data.

To manage the states I use Redux.

**Submit Function**

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { title, content, audio} = this.state;
    let formDataStory = new FormData(); // create form formData
    formDataStory.append('audio', audio); // add audio to formData
    formDataStory.append('title', title); // add title to formData
    formDataStory.append('content', content); // add content to formData
    this.props.addStory(formDataStory); // call addStory function with formDataStory as Input to create new Story
    this.setState({
      title: "", // clear title field after submission
      content:"", // clear content field after submission
    });
    this.inputRef.current.value = ''; // clear file field after submission 
  };
```

**Add Story Action**

```
export const addStory = formDataStory => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios.post(apiBase +"/story/", formDataStory, tokenConfig(getState) )
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(createMessage({ addStory: "Story Added" }));
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

At the moment I don't know how to implement this, and I haven't found a good read about it (my assumption is something like this: if the story is successfully added, than -> clear form, else -> keep form). I am happy about every support on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use a .then and .catch after calling "this.props.addStory(formDataStory)" if you use a promise in addStory definition:

    export const addStory = formDataStory => (dispatch, getState) =>
new Promiuse((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.post(apiBase +"/story/", formDataStory, tokenConfig(getState) )
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(createMessage({ addStory: "Story Added" }));
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
      resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    }
  );
});

And then: 

    onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let { title, content, audio} = this.state;
  let formDataStory = new FormData(); // create form formData
  formDataStory.append('audio', audio); // add audio to formData
  formDataStory.append('title', title); // add title to formData
  formDataStory.append('content', content); // add content to formData
  this.props.addStory(formDataStory)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          title: "", // clear title field after submission
          content:"", // clear content field after submission
        });
        this.inputRef.current.value = ''; // clear file field after submission 
      }) // call addStory function with formDataStory as Input to create new Story
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In redux its a bit longer process but no option than this.
First check in the action when axios req failed due to some error so call dispatch mathod and pass dispatch({type: ERROR, payload: err.message}) and then paass the boolean value in reducers like in initial state in reducer set isError:false but when action send action.type is ERROR then change isError false to true in such case . Then in main comp call that isError by using mapstatetoProps and check that either coming props from redux having property isError true or if isError is false then clear form otherwise empty